# javapns handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I am trying to send push notifications to IOS using **[javapns](https://code.google.com/archive/p/javapns/)**. Path to the keystore(P12) file and its password is correctly mentioned in the code.

```
List < PushedNotification > NOTIFICATIONS = Push.payload(payload, "/home/sunil/Downloads/pushCertCurrent.p12", "password", false, "7964b31ec8b8a194f8c6b84924088d7b29bd98ecc28162e771f623d5ef0a39b6");
```

But while sending notification to the device having device token mentioned as last parameter in the above code, I am getting **javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error**

I have attached debugger with **-Djavax.net.debug=all** parameter and getting following log in the console.

This is a part of log which I am getting.

```
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, internal_error
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
    at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:427)
    at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:366)
    at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:336)
    at javapns.Push.sendPayload(Push.java:178)
    at javapns.Push.payload(Push.java:149)
    at com.icube.apns.TestPushNotificationApp.main(TestPushNotificationApp.java:35)
17063 [main] INFO javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - Attempt failed (Received fatal alert: internal_error)... trying again
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
18495 [main] DEBUG javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer  - Creating SSLSocket to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(30000) called
26600 [main] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - Reading responses
main, setSoTimeout(5000) called
```

Please help me figuring out where I am doing something wrong and is this a problem from my side or from apple's side.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, It wasn't an issue with my code. I just regenerated the apple's certificate/Keystore(P12) and it started to work, there might be some issue in generating keystore.

Comment: Hi @Sunil, did you take any special care while generating the p12? I'm facing the exact same trouble. I followed the "standard" procedure, namely, generate the certificate in the Apple Developer Centre, download it, and export it with the private key from the Keychain app. Is that the way to do it?